# What will the 737 MAX 7, 8, and 9 ICAO IDs be?

Tags: boeing-737, icao

Since the ICAO identifiers B737, B738, and B739 are already taken, what will the ICAO identifier for the 737 MAX 7, 8, and 9 be? Would it possibly be B73M7 etc?

Comment: This seems to be entirely speculative.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speculating on future events, we don't have a crystal ball

Comment: @jwenting Since a designator has already been assigned to the 737 MAX series, there is no speculation at all, just reporting of a fact. No need to close it IMHO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The new [Boeing 737 MAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_MAX) is based on the [Boeing 737 Next Generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Next_Generation) family, which it will replace. Also note that 737 MAX is still under development and is scheduled to release in 2017.

**Update:**

[image]
([Source](http://www.icao.int/publications/DOC8643/Pages/Search.aspx))

The first 7 is omitted and the suffix is now an M for Max, e.g. B37M for the Boeing 737 MAX 7.

Wikipedia has complete list of ICAO codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ICAO_aircraft_type_designators).

---

[ICAO Aircraft Type Designators](http://www.icao.int/publications/DOC8643/Pages/Search.aspx): Search for Boeing and you will find 737 MAX in the list.

Comment: That somewhat surprises me, as I'm sure some 737NG's will be in service for some time after the MAX comes out. Oh well!

Comment: @nathreed they're effectively 738 and 739 aircraft with upgraded interior and engines. For ATC purposes they're no different, so no need to distinguish them.

Answer (score 1):

Initially they will go with the same designators as the B737NG series. If the performance is very different from the NG, new designators may be chosen. I don't think this will be necessary.

---

Note that an ICAO aircraft type designator is always 4 characters; B73M7 is too long.